# how to correctly indent nested switch statements in php with vim

Tags: php, vim, nested, switch-statement, indentation

The following php script gets the wrong indentation in latest vim (`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 30 2013 13:07:23), Included patches: 1-131`):

```
<?
switch($one) {
case 'a':
    switch($two) {
    case 'b':
    }
    case 'c': # <-- should be one level higher
}
```

The `case 'c':` statement should be one level higher:

```
<?
switch($one) {
case 'a':
    switch($two) {
    case 'b':
    }
case 'c':
}
```

I already tried the latest [php indent plugin](https://github.com/2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm) 1.40 without change to this. How can the nested switch statement be indented correctly? Is there any better php indentation plugin getting this right?

thanks for help.

Comment: I completely understand the desire to get it perfect, but how often do you really nest switches?  I'd probably just file a bug report on the PHP indent plugin Github project.

Comment: right, reporting it to the author, just opened an issue: https://github.com/2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm/issues/25 -- nevertheless, I've got some few php scripts laying around with this issue which got me annoyed so much to report it here, so I'd be happy to have this fixed :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by mainter, changelog for commit: https://github.com/2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm/commit/b416ade